# Why is my method not being invoked by variable name

Tags: javascript

When I invoke a method through a variable name i keep getting

```
TypeError: window[$hello] is not a function
```

I have been reading other posts about this in stack overflow, but its doesn't seem to be working on my code. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it. Below is my code! Thanks!

```
function Actions(){



    function hello(){

        alert("hello world");


    }


    (function(){

        $(document).on("change",".item-actions",function(){

            var $hello = "hello";

        window[$hello]();


        });




    })();




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hello()` function is local to the `Actions()` function, and therefore it won't be visible on the `window` object. Only global functions are on `window`.

You can use your own object for a similar effect:

```
function Actions(){

    var functions = {
        hello: function hello(){
            alert("hello world");
        },
        // more ...
    };


    (function(){

        $(document).on("change",".item-actions",function(){

            var $hello = "hello";

            functions[$hello]();
        });
    })();
}
```

Comment: Quick question. How can I create a call back  instead of writing it directly in the object. 

Example. hello: function hello(){
            alert("hello world");
        },

How I have like hello : "hello"

where hello() would be defined separately

Comment: @json2021 Well the property values in the "lookup" object can be functions defined as in my example, or they can be references to other functions - functions declared somewhere else, or parameters, or whatever. I'm not 100% sure I know what you're asking however; you can always ask a new question!